# JAVA: How to check if website document contains a word?

Tags: java, web

**I currently have the follow method:**

```
try {
           URL url = new URL("http://auth.h.gp/HAKUNA%20MATATA.txt");
           Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
           BotScript.log("Something went wrong =/ Error code:");
           ex.printStackTrace();
           stop();
        }
```

However, how do I check if it contains a word? I've never worked with Scanners before and I found this snippet online.

Thank you.

Comment: You could always start by [reading the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), though you probably should be using something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), not a `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, that looks good so far.

You can then use Scanner's [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) method to get each word. You can also query [`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) to see if there's another token available to avoid errors.

```
boolean foundPumbaa = false;
while (s.hasNext()) {
    if (s.next().equalsIgnoreCase("pumbaa")) {
        foundPumbaa = true;
        System.out.println("We found Pumbaa"); // do something
        break;
    }
}
if (!foundPumbaa) {
    System.out.println("We didn't find Pumbaa");
}
```

**EDIT** in response to comment:
Yes, you can turn the text into a `String`. The best way to do this is probably with a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

From the [Java Tutorial, "Reading Directly from a URL"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html):

> The following small Java program uses openStream() to get an input
>   stream on the URL http://www.oracle.com/. It then opens a
>   BufferedReader on the input stream and reads from the BufferedReader
>   thereby reading from the URL. Everything read is copied to the
>   standard output stream:
>
> ```
> import java.net.*;
> import java.io.*;
>
> public class URLReader {
>     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>
>         URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
>         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
>         new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
>
>         String inputLine;
>         while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
>             System.out.println(inputLine);
>         in.close();
>     }
> }
> ```

In a real program, instead of `main throws Exception`, you'd have that in a `try`-`catch` block and catch an `IOException` and some various `URLExceptions`. But this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I could turn the webpages text into a String? Would that be ex; `String websource = s.next()`?